# Filter with useState not working and showing Blank Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, use-effect, use-state

I want to update the items when i click on the buttons there are two categoires veg and non veg. Whenever category state changes i want to call handle category and setItems to the new data but this is somehow making the whole page blank. What am I doing wrong here?

```
export default function Products() {
    const [items,setItems] = useState(data)
    const [category,setCategory] = useState("veg");

    const handleCategory = () => {
      return items.filter(item => item.category == category)
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
      var filterData = handleCategory();
      setItems(filterData);
    },[category])

    
    return (
        <div className='products'>
         <h1>Foodzie</h1>
         <Button onClick={() => setCategory("veg")}>Vegetarian</Button> 
         <Button onClick={() => setCategory("Non veg")}>Non Vegetarian</Button>
            <Grid
                container
                spacing={2}
                direction="row"
                justify="flex-start"
                alignItems="flex-start"
            >
            {items && items.products.map(({ id, name,price, desc, small, large }) => (
              <Grid item xs={6} xs={12} sm={6} md={3} >
                <Link to={`/${name}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                <Card key={id} className="card">
                <CardMedia component="img" image={small}/>
                <div>
                  <h2>{name}</h2>
                  <h3>{price}</h3>
                </div>
                </Card>
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            ))}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

After making the change to anonymous function yeah it doesn't show blank in the first render but. Still the change is not working only the initial state works. When i click on the second button the filter doesn't work it changes to blank.

Comment: your setCategory will be run at render btw, try <Button onClick={() => setCategory("veg")}>

Comment: Wrap your funciton in useCallback , it should work eg:  `const handleCategory = useCallback(() => {
      return items.filter(item => item.category == category)
    },[items]);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `onClick` on your `Button` components.
You should use them like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => setCategory("veg")}>Vegetarian</Button>
<Button onClick={() => setCategory("Non veg")}>Non Vegetarian</Button>
```

### Update

You are modifying the items array itself in the first filter call. You must preserve the actual list of items so that you can use them again to filter.

On the second line of your code, you set the initial value of items using a variable `data` (`const [items,setItems] = useState(data)`). So, always use that variable to filter the list because it will always contain both `veg` & `Non veg`.

```
    const handleCategory = () => {
      // always filter from the initial list which I believe is `data`
      return data.filter(item => item.category == category)
    }
```

Comment: After making the change to anonymous function yeah it doesn't show blank in the first render but. Still the change is not working only the initial state works. When i click on the second button the filter doesn't work it changes to blank. I meant the first filter of veg works but "Non veg" doesn't it just shows blank.

Comment: Ahh! I missed this. I have updated my answer to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setCategory("veg")` and `setCategory("Non veg")` at the time of rendering and **not when the user clicks the button**.

You need to either create some functions that do this inside the component, or just use an arrow function in the render part.

```
<Button onClick={() => setCategory("veg")}>Vegetarian</Button>
<Button onClick={() => setCategory("Non veg")}>Non Vegetarian</Button>
```

The other issue is related to filtering. When doing filtering on an array is a good practice to store another state that holds the filtered values and map over that.

```
const [items,setItems] = useState(data);
const [filterdItems, setFilteredItems] = useState(data);
const [category,setCategory] = useState("veg");

useEffect(() =>{
  setFilteredItems(items.filter(item => item.category == category));
},[items, category])
```

and the use `filteredItems` in the render.

```
{filteredItems && filteredItems.products.map(({ id, name,price, desc, small, large }) => (
```

Comment: After making the change to anonymous function yeah it doesn't show blank in the first render but. Still the change is not working only the initial state works. When i click on the second button the filter doesn't work it changes to blank. I meant the first filter of veg works but "Non veg" doesn't it just shows blank.

Comment: That's because you are filtering all items based on the first condition. When selecting the second  condition, none of the items are actually matching it so you end up with a second array. I'll update my answer to showcase this issue